# Number of bytes of CString in C++

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8, mfc, c-strings

I have a Unicode string stored in `CString` and I need to know the number bytes this string takes in UTF-8 encoding. I know CString has a method `getLength()`, but that returns number of characters, not bytes.

I tried (beside other things) converting to char array, but I get (logically, I guess) only array of `wchar_t`, so this doesn't solve my problem.

To be clear about my goal. For the input lets say `"aaa"` I want "3" as output (since "a" takes one byte in UTF-8). But for the input "āaa", I'd like to see output "4" (since ā is two byte character).

I think this has to be quite common request, but even after 1,5 hours of search and experimenting, I couldn't find the correct solution.

I have very little experience with Windows programming, so maybe I left out some crucial information. If you feel like that, please let me know, I'll add any information you request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As your CString contains a series of `wchar_t`, you can just use [`WideCharToMultiByte`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-widechartomultibyte) with the output charset as `CP_UTF8`. The function will return the number of bytes written to the output buffer, or the length of the UTF-8 encoded string

```
LPWSTR instr;
char outstr[MAX_OUTSTR_SIZE];
int utf8_len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, instr, -1, outstr, MAX_OUTSTR_SIZE, NULL, NULL);
```

If you don't need the output string, you can simply set the output buffer size to 0

> - `cbMultiByte`
>
>   Size, in bytes, of the buffer indicated by lpMultiByteStr. If this parameter is set to 0, the function returns the required buffer size for lpMultiByteStr and makes no use of the output parameter itself.

In that case the function will return the number of bytes in UTF-8 without really outputting anything

```
int utf8_len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, instr, -1, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

If your CString is really `CStringA`, i.e. `_UNICODE` is not defined, then you need to use `Multi­Byte­To­Wide­Char` to convert the string to UTF-16 and then convert from UTF-16 to UTF-8 with `Wide­Char­To­Multi­byte`. See [How do I convert an ANSI string directly to UTF-8?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100603-00/?p=13823) But new code should never be compiled without Unicode support anyway

Comment: Keep in mind that if you set the `cchWideChar` parameter to -1, `WideCharToMultiByte()` takes the null terminator into account, and the resulting length includes the null terminator. If you don't want that, you have to set `cchWideChar` to the actual length of the data being passed to the `lpWideCharStr` parameter.